# What tools can I use to create 3D graphics and then export them as a 2D sprite sheet?

Tags: graphics, 2d, isometric

I've been working on 2D games for a long time now (because 2D is all I know how to do) and want to step it up a notch. I don't want to go fully 3D because I don't think I have the mathematical knowledge to work with 3D graphics, but instead want to start developing some graphics that lie somewhere inbetween.

By inbetween I mean graphics that will still render as 2D, but may have been created using 3D software and then exported at various angles. Some examples of the style could include:

- Age of Empires 1.
- Diablo 1 & 2.
- Starcraft 1.

Is there any software used specifically for creating a 3D model and then generating a 2D sprite-sheet from it? Here is an example of such graphics that may help in making sense:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender is free 3D modeling tool, where you can make sprite sheet out of the model. I don't know how to do this but I know it's possible, because my friend is using it for our game (he is making 3D spaceship models and transforming them into 2D sprites)

http://www.blender.org/

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such a specialized software, but have you considered simply using a 3d engine with a fixed camera looking at the scene from above and all objects at ground level?

That way you can use regular tools for modeling and still have the logic and (with a few settings to the physics engine) physics of a of a 2D game.

Answer (score 0):

[Unity engine](http://unity3d.com/support/resources/tutorials/2d-gameplay-tutorial.html) might be able to help you.